# Copying range between sheets and skipping the header

Tags: vba

I wanted to skip copying cell by cell for the sake of speed - if I wanted to copy the whole range except the first row, how can I make something like:

```
Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A2:A").Copy Worksheets("sheet2").Range("F2:F")
```

work? The two worksheets will also always have the same number of rows. The above keeps leading to an application-defined / object-defined error.

Comment: Well, because Range Object need properly defined range. It should be either A:A (complete column A) or A2:A1048576 (ColumnA except first row). Do the same thing with column F (destination). Optionally, in destination, you can provide only first cell. So, try this:

Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A2:A1048576").Copy Worksheets("sheet2").Range("F2")

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
With Worksheets("sheet1") 'reference "sheet1" worksheet
    .range("A2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)).Copy Worksheets("sheet2").range("F2") ' copy referenced worksheet column A range from row 2 down to last not empty one and paste it to "sheet2" worksheet starting from its cell "F2"
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

Or

```
With Worksheets("sheet1")
    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Worksheets("sheet2").Range("F2:F" & lastRow) = .Range("A2:A" & lastRow)
End With
```